# Can't install Ruby on Rails with RVM on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to install RVM on my Ubuntu machine.

I have used curl to get RVM, but some RVM  commands (install, requirements) throw this apt-get error:

```
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
```

type rvm | head -1 returns

```
rvm is a function
-bash: type: write error: Broken pipe
```

which gem

```
/usr/bin/gem
```

I have checked the "Run command as a login shell" option

Steps followed from this [tutorial](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/):

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto
. ~/.bash_profile
rvm requirements - doesn't work properly
```

I have also looked at the [official RVM documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/#explained), but it seems to be very similar.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I managed to do it. I disabled all the third party ppa URLs and it installed smoothly.

Comment: what are the steps you performed,put here.

Comment: I followed this [tutorial](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/). I got stuck at rvm requirements.

Comment: mentioned the link in your question.

Comment: getting exactly same problem :(

Comment: @NinjaTurtle I installed "Sublime text", may be my sources.list file changed that time. Did you do same?

Comment: [quickly get a fresh ubuntu install ready for ruby dev](http://www.isotope11.com/blog/update-v1-dot-0-1-quickly-get-a-fresh-ubuntu-install-ready-for-ruby-dev)

Comment: i also had to disable third-party PPAs.  i did this by just temporarily moving all the files under /etc/apt/sources.list.d into a sub folder.  then I ran the curl command and moved them back.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are some important packages your system needs before install rvm. Run at the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev \
curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev \
sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake \
libtool bison subversion nodejs
```

Then install rvm with:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Now you need to put a setting in your `.bashrc` to add rvm to PATH for scripting. Run:

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Open a new terminal and test rvm.

Comment: Sorry.. I just feel this answer though solves the OP's issue, it does not create a better world by explaining what issues each of the steps are solving. In short, I would like why's to be added as well.

Comment: Yes this works, but there should be an additional flag that takes care of the dependencies for you, as is the case with most other applications.

Answer (score 1):

run

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and then try again.

Comment: run this in your terminal and try again
"source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

Comment: @SachinSingh probably it would be good,if you post the step by step installation process, what you did for your own installation.

Comment: i recommend rvm installation through rvm website.

after installing rvm add this line to very end of .bashrc file
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

and close all terminals and open and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Hye Guys!!

I got the solution. Actually error is because the information we need for installation is not available at sever define for software & update. I change it to from my local "Server from India" (In my case) to "Main Server".

It's working perfectly for me now :)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with my install, and then I fully read the details that terminal left once the install was finished.

Try using `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm`

Once I did that, the function `type rvm | head -1` returned `rvm is a function`

Answer (score 1):

In my Case i fixed the error by:

> rvmsudo rvm install 1.9.3
>
> rvm --default 1.9.3
>
> rvmsudo rvm remove 1.9.3
>
> rvm install 1.9.3

[Source](http://junaidpven.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/how-to-install-ruby-and-rails-with-rvm-in-ubuntu-11-10/)

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling repository which appear at 404 sudo apt-get update or viewing logs rvm. The fact is that when you install rvm is trying to update a list of your packages and if you have 404 to go to bed =)

Answer (score 0):

`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`     .
paste this in your terminal window.I used this.It worked for me.for RVM for ruby
`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails`     .
Use these to install RVM with ruby on rails

Answer (score 0):

For people that know nothing about Linux or are newbies to Linux (like me) those are steps how to solve this (explanation, that was given above, was not that clear for me :) ).

1. Go to Package Manager, tab Settings, Preferences
2. In the opened window you'll see Other Software tab or something like that with links to servers. In my case one of these (it's mentioned in the error log that was produced by rvm) was causing errors and was not available (404 errors). I just unchecked it.
3. run `rmv dependencies` only when you closed Package Manager, or you'll get error saying that something is locked at the moment.

And everything now is installed successfully! :)

Answer (score 0):

The most common symptom of this problem occurs (as seth2810 [hinted at](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24567820/141881)) with non-zero exit codes from an `apt-get update` command, which `rvm requirements` expects. You should run this command yourself (with sudo) and check for any problems.

If you have 404s in the output, check that the package sources for the bad URLs are still correct/current. You can remove package sources more easily with `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`, followed by `sudo add-apt-repository --remove {URL_OF_PROBLEM_PACKAGE_SOURCE}` for each failed url.

If you have something hinting at packages with 'unmet dependencies', try `sudo apt-get -f install`. This command attempts to fix incomplete installs by fetching missing packages and works most of the time. Otherwise... by this point you probably have a more specific error to google for anyway!