# Rails working in specific terminal only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed rails in ubuntu its working fine in the terminal which i installed, once i close the terminal and open it again and when i check for `rails -v`  am getting following error. Again i tried installing it but no luck same thing repeated again.

[This is the installation link i followed](http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html)

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * rails
 * ruby-railties-3.2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

checked for `ruby -v`

```
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

and also for `gem list rails`

```
The program 'gem' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.9.1
 * rubygems
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
```

Comment: can you please give me what it is showing after `gem list rails`

Comment: As per your post ....You have not installed ruby please install it or you can use `rvm`

Comment: Please follow this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

Comment: I installed `ruby rvm and rails` following the steps in the above link. but when i close the terminal its not coming again.

Comment: If `rvm list` is showing such type of error then the packages are not installed properly can you please let me know which version of ubuntu have you used

Comment: @Rajashi I followed the step from your link when i type this line `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` am getting link this `bash: /root/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory`

Comment: can you please run this command once `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Comment: @Rajashi i tried in ubuntu 12.04 and because of this error i changed my ubuntu version to 13.04. But no use same error.

Comment: Actually I am using ubuntu 13.04 and all are working like a heaven

Comment: You are attempting to install RVM as the root user. You should not do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is rails (and gem) are not in your PATH after you restart your terminal session but since your system sees them as packages in the repositories, it suggests you install those packages. Using the repository packages is generally a bad idea with Rails because those packages are out-of-date.

Follow the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17282941/636044) to install Ruby and then install rails using

```
gem install rails
```

Remember to install RVM as a regular user, not as root.

Edit: Based on your comments, the most likely reason why you're losing rails is because you installed RVM as the root user but you are a regular user after you restart the terminal.

Comment: It's not working because the root user and your local user have a different PATH (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) set when you launch a new terminal. The root user's PATH sees ruby and rails while your local user does not. More importantly, if you read the RVM installation documentation (https://rvm.io/rvm/install) you will see under "Installation Explained" that "Using this type of installation without knowledge how umask works is a big security risk." Tools like RVM are designed to install Ruby in the most secure way possible and that means not using the root user.